# How can I create an event with natural language parsing in Calendar?

Tags: release-loki, calendar

The blog post [Loki 0.4 Stable Release!](http://blog.elementary.io/post/147637979911/loki-04-stable-release) mentions:

> Calendar in Loki introduces natural language creation for events. For
>   example, type “Meeting with Dan tomorrow at 8 at Starbucks” and
>   Calendar will pre-fill the event title, participant, date, time, and
>   location tabs with the relevant information.

But I haven't been able to find where I can type this. Slingshot simply indicates "No results", there doesn't seem to be a new field or button in the Calender app itself and there is no button for this in the Calendar Wingpanel integration .

I'm using Using Elementary OS 0.4 Loki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Calendar and click the "Create New Event" toolitem in the headerbar
2. Under "Title", type in the name of your event. For example "Dancing at 7pm"
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the arrow icon in the entry

Calendar will do its best to parse the title and fill out other details for you :)